# Multithreading Tkinter and console

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

Hi I try to make an overlay window in tkinter but i want still use my console but i am not able to do that.
What am i doing wrong with the threads?(line 39,40)
Is this error caused by tkinter mainloop?
How can i fix this issue?

Thanks for help

```
from threading import Thread
import tkinter
import os
import keyboard
import time

FONT = "{Verdana} 10 bold"

btest = True

txt = """
    Text here
"""
root = tkinter.Tk()

def overlay():
    text = tkinter.Text(root,relief=tkinter.FLAT, 
                font=FONT,state='normal', height=5, bg='grey70', fg='blue')
    text.insert(tkinter.END, txt)
    text.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)     #make it readonly with calling state=diabled    ,state=normal is write
    text.pack(expand=tkinter.YES, fill=tkinter.BOTH)

    button = tkinter.Button(root, text='Exit', bd=1, command=quit)
    button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, fill=tkinter.X)

    text.insert(tkinter.END, txt)

    root.geometry('200x250+1710-820')
    root.overrideredirect(1) # fenster ohne aussen rum :-)

    root.attributes('-alpha', 0.75) # fenster transparent
    root.attributes('-topmost', 1) # fenster immer im vordergrund
    root.mainloop()

def printgui():
    os.system("cls")
    print(f"Test: {btest} [alt]")

Thread(target=printgui()).start()
Thread(target=overlay()).start()

while True:
    if(keyboard.is_pressed("alt")):         #if u press "alt" it will change true to False
        btest = not btest
        time.sleep(0.2)
        printgui()

    if(keyboard.is_pressed("delete")):
        print("\n")
        print("Exiting")
        time.sleep(3)
        os._exit(1)
```

Comment: What's that `keyboard` module?

Comment: it recognizes actions on the keyboard

Comment: Yes, but it's not a standard library module.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed mis-starting your threads:

```
Thread(target=printgui()).start()
Thread(target=overlay()).start()
```

should be

```
Thread(target=printgui).start()
Thread(target=overlay).start()
```

so the functions are not called immediately in your current thread, but in the newly started threads.

However, Tkinter might not work from a non-default thread (it certainly violently doesn't on MacOS). Here's a reworking where the console stuff (and background work, as it were) is done on another thread. However, you *also* can't do cross-thread calls to Tkinter, seo instead of directly trying to do e.g. `text.insert()` in `console_thread`, a Queue is set up, and a message handler that reads messages from that Queue and applies the changes on the main thread. It's a little janky, but it works...

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue, Empty
import tkinter
import sys
import time

queue = Queue()


def console_thread():
    x = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.3)
        queue.put(("write", str(x)))
        x += 1
        print(x)


Thread(target=console_thread).start()


root = tkinter.Tk()
text = tkinter.Text(root)
text.insert(tkinter.END, "Hello!\n")
# text.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
text.pack(expand=tkinter.YES, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Exit")
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, fill=tkinter.X)
root.attributes("-topmost", 1)


def handle_messages():
    while True:
        try:
            item = queue.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            break
        if item[0] == "write":
            text.insert(tkinter.END, item[1])
        else:
            print("???", item)
    root.after(100, handle_messages)


handle_messages()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am only able to see the console but not the tkinter gui

Comment: ok it works with a thread now but how can i make that i am able to use inputs or keyboard actions while both windows are open

Comment: What do you mean with "inputs or keyboard actions"?

Comment: like if i press "alt" it should change True to False and display it on the console